# Table stretch to parent div, and columns to table, using css flexbox isn't working as expected

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I have a div with a table on it. I simply want the table to occupy the whole div, then stretch the second column and its contained inputs, so that the inputs will be as large as possible (i.e. col1+col2 = div width).

All this is inside another div, so absolute measures such as `100%` aren't an option.

In the following code, if I remove the `flex-grow:1` from `tr`, nothing changes. But if then I remove the `display:flex` from `t`, the table won't stretch to the div anymore. Isn't it strange? I have tried including all these `display:flex` and `flex-grow:1` down to `td2`, but it doesn't work, either.

And please don't tell me to avoid tables in formatting, because no other option works in all cases like tables do.

```css
#d {
  background-color:blue;
  padding:2px;
  width:400px;
  display:flex;
}
#t {
  background-color:red;
  padding:2px;
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex;
}
#tr {
  background-color:green;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div id='d'>
  <table id='t'>
    <tr id='tr'>
      <td id='td1'>col1</td>
      <td id='td2'><input type='text'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like flexbox and table hate each other. So I found out I should be using [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.wrapper > div {
  padding:2px;
  margin:2px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-gap:2px;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
  background-color: green;
}
.one {
  text-align:right;
  align-self:center;
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:1;
}
.two {
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row:1;
}
.three {
  text-align:right;
  align-self:center;
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:2;
}
.four {
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row:2;
}
.wrapper > div > input {
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">Line 1, with long text:</div>
  <div class="two"><input></div>
  <div class="three">Line 2:</div>
  <div class="four"><input></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but it would be a pain if I had many lines on my table.